# Custom fields with advance search and search builder returning wrong results

Tags: contacts, search, search-results, search-builder

We have a custom fields to define our contacts regions as tick box for the region, after we upgraded to CivicRM  4.6.8 when we search using this custom field to find the client in a particular region we get all the region as if this custom filed is ignored. Not sure if this is a bug in the new version or not?
we have the same issue from search builder and advance search, strange enough using custom report returned the correct results.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: Search builder and the result showing all regions coming back]

Comment: sounds odd. may help if you can provide some screenshots of the 'field' settings, and the outcome of an Adv. Search. eg does the 'results' show the custom field in the query explanation, or not. if it does not, what happens if you create a new custom field and test with that, does that work ok? also perhaps do the equivalent test on demo to confirm behaviour there.

Comment: Attached an image that shows the search builder and you can see the result returning all the regions not only the selected region